# Pasar variable desde el controlador a varias vistas en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo la siguiente `funcion edit` en mi controlador

```
public function edit($id){
        $ficha= Data::findOrFail($id);
        return view('ficha.edit')->with('ficha', $ficha);
}
```

Esta envía a la vista 'ficha.edit' la variable `$ficha`, pero quisiera saber como hacer para enviar el valor de la variable `$ficha` a otras vistas de mi proyecto desde la misma función.

Comment: Podrías utilizar [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers), acá te dejo unos tutoriales que podrías seguir: [Uso de los View Composer en Laravel 5](https://styde.net/uso-de-view-composer-laravel-5/) y [Sharing Data Between Views Using Laravel View Composers](https://scotch.io/tutorials/sharing-data-between-views-using-laravel-view-composers)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes modificar tu función del controlador de la siguiente manera:

```
public function edit($id){
        $ficha= Data::findOrFail($id);
        return $ficha;
}
```

Y en la vista en tu script la mandas a llamar mediante una petición get.

```
 <script>
 $scope.obtener= function($id){     
    $http.get(uploadUrl+"/"+$id)
    .then(function success(response){
        $scope.ficha= response.data;
        return $scope.ficha;
    });
    console.log($scope.checar);
};
</script>
```

En este caso yo estoy usando angular, pero puedes hacer algo similar con jquery o solo javascript. Y ya solo mandas a llamar la función para que se carguen los datos.
Espero solucione tu duda.